# Raspberry Pi Zero W running Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi

I am currently running a Hello World program on my Raspberry Pi Zero W with Node. My only code is a console.log statement. This program takes up to 5 seconds to run. I have also ran some smaller python programs which display/animate text over an OLED screen. The python code seems to work fast with no problems. I have seen that Node does run slow for some people with the raspberry pi but this program is about as basic as it gets. I am wondering what I am doing wrong or if someone could explain to me why this is?

Comment: Have you tried running more than just the single line? It might just bee startup-time which is that long and the program might run fine after that.

Comment: I'm running node.js apps on RPi Zero without any issues. Also this question is not a good question for StackOverflow.

Comment: It does seem to be the startup time but this still does seem to be quite excessive for me. Where should I ask the question then?